# Add a column with the same value to the results (not to table on db)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Is there an easy way to add a column with `NewColumnName` containing only one value across the rows (i.e `NameIwantToAssign`) to CTE? I do not want to change the table in database, only I want to have the new column in the results. Here is something I have cooked. But this is very bad idea with respect to performance. Please help.

```
SELECT 
     A.Something
    ,CASE 
    WHEN A.Something=NULL THEN 'NameIwantToAssign'
        ELSE 'NameIwantToAssign'
    END AS 'NewColumnName'
FROM TabA A
```

**Update.**
Surprisingly, the method proposed by Raging Bull, which is very simple, is much slower than this code:

```
WITH B AS (SELECT 'NameIwantToAssign' as 'NewColumn')

SELECT * TabA A
LEFT JOIN B
ON A.Key <> B.NewColumn
```

BTW. I would like to get rid of `<>` from an `ON` statement for performance reasons. Is it possible to use something better then `<>`, something like `IS NOT`, `NOT EXISTS` etc?

Comment: I don't understand what your case expression is for, regardless of whether A.Something is null or not the same thing is returned? The good news is SQL Server is smart enough to figure this out an optimises away your case expression, therefore what you have posted, although a long winded way of achieving a constant value will not perform badly at all.

Comment: I have a complex query and I just want to add table name for the table I use. It will be constant of course.

Comment: The updated query you have posted is semantically equivalent to `SELECT A.*, NULLIF(A.Key, 'NameIwantToAssign') AS NewColumn FROM TabA AS A` - Have you actually identified any performance issues with your original query? What evidence do you have the performance bottle neck is due to adding a constant value as a column?

Comment: @GarethD My original code takes up 30 seconds. The query in update 15 seconds. The query Red Bull proposed takes up 45 seconds. Your query takes 24 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

To select a value along the result:

```
SELECT 'ValueIWantToAssign' as NameIwantToAssign,
       A.Something
FROM TabA
```

If you want to select a value if `A.Something` is null, you can use `COALESCE` in SQL.

```
SELECT COALESCE(A.Something,'ValueIwantToAssign')
FROM TabA
```

**Explanation:**

If the field A.Something is null, then it will select 'NameIwantToAssign'.

Read more about `COALESCE` [**here**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx).

Comment: Surprisingly, adding such a column your way with a single value takes up more time then inner join of two complex tables in my query. It takes approximately 30 seconds for 40k rows.